# Jenkins gradle task configuration for multi module project

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build, multi-module

I have a multi module gradle project and trying to configure build in Jenkins web interface.
Also I need possibility to choose module or build the whole project, then create docker image and upload it to the repository.

I've created `Choice parameter` with variable `$PROJECT` and module enumeration, like this:

```
module1
module2
module3
```

Then I added stage `Invoke gradle script`.

If I add gradle task `$PROJECT:clean $PROJECT:build $PROJECT:jib`, it will work fine for the selected module. But if I don't select module, it won't build the whole project, because of

```
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/gradle7.1.1/bin/gradle -DGRADLE_TASK= -PGRADLE_TASK= :clean :build :jib
Task 'clean' not found in root project 'name_of_project'.
```

Tasks have unnecessary `:` symbol if module was not selected.

If I add gradle task `clean build jib` it will do these tasks for the whole project always no matter which module is selected.

Also I tried to create stage `Run shell command` before `Invoke Gradle script` with this code:

```
GRADLE_TASK="clean build jib"
if [ -z $PROJECT ] 
then 
  GRADLE_TASK="$PROJECT:clean $PROJECT:build $PROJECT:jib"
fi
```

And use it in `gradle task` field like this:

```
$GRADLE_TASK
```

But it doesn't take effect, because of:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/gradle7.1.1/bin/gradle -DGRADLE_TASK= -PGRADLE_TASK= $GRADLE_TASK
Task '$GRADLE_TASK' not found in root project 'name_of_project'
```

I tried some variants of this variable, but it doesn't work too:

```
- $GRADLE_TASK
- ${GRADLE_TASK}
- "${GRADLE_TASK}"
- GRADLE_TASK
```

Can anybody help with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's necessary to run both the `build` and `clean` tasks? I expect that you only need to run `./gradlew :my-project:jib`, and Gradle will rebuild if it's required. If so, I think your script will become more simple.

Comment: Thanks, @aSemy. Yes, I can only use `jib` without `clean` and `build`. But it won't help with the main question. How to do it flexible. 
If module is selected, then `:module:jib`.
If module is not selected, then just `jib`.